# Unable to connect to db ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, xampp

I have the following code. I'm using XAMPP to run a local MySQL database, but I can't connect to it using sequelize.

```js
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const user_auth_db = new Sequelize('db_name', 'root', '', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: "3306",
});

try {
    await user_auth_db.authenticate();
    console.log("Connection has been established succesfully");
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to db", error);
}
```

The error is the following:

```
parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  },
```

I tried changing the port, password and user and try it that way but it didn't work.

Comment: any solution for this. from cpanel to cpanel

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I could not connect to my MYSQL Server from anywhere. It didn't even load on the MYSL Workbench. This happened after my computer crashed and I restarted it. I fixed it by going into the MySQL Installer that you used to first use MYSQL and reconfigure the server. My server worked like normal after.